# Getting all URLs on multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get all these URLs from a website, but I only seem to be able to get the first URL. How can I match all the URLs?

So far I've tried

```
auto">(.*?)<\/pre>
```

and:

```
auto">(.*?)\s<\/pre>
```

I've tried adding several modifiers such as `m` and `i`, but it didn't seem to help.

This is what I'm searching:

```
auto">http://url-one.com
http://url-two.com
http://url-three.com
http://url-four.com
http://url-five.com</pre>
```

Can someone help me understand what I am missing?

Comment: Need the `s`-[flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for making the dot also match newlines: `/auto">(.*?)<\/pre>/s` see [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pA6gE2/1)

Comment: Ah right, thanks i read the /s as single line but working now.

Comment: @Jonny5, why do I see so many people post answers as comments instead of answers?

Comment: @user1717828: That is a good question for [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @user1717828 Dunno :) I thought it's too little for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick Answer

As Jonny5 hinted in his comment, `.` does not match newline characters by default: so `(.*?)` will not match beyond the first line without the `s` regex modifier, and his suggestion is then the quick answer:

```
/auto">(.*?)<\/pre>/s
```

You can check out his [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA6gE2/1) or related PHP code...

```
$re = "/auto\">(.*?)<\\/pre>/s"; 
$str = "auto\">http://url-one.com\nhttp://url-two.com\nhttp://url-three.com\nhttp://url-four.com\nhttp://url-five.com</pre>"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

...for reference.

## Digging Deeper

However, there is a little more going on here.

### i and m Modifiers

*First*, regardless whether you use the `i` or `m` modifier(s), no line of the sample text would match with `auto">` at the beginning *and* `<\/pre>` at the end of the pattern.  You would have to group and follow each with a quantifier to make it optional (e.g. `(?:auto">)?` and `(?:<\/pre>)?`) to match each line of the sample text.

### m Requires Matching Globally

*Second*, the `m` modifier would necessitate matching globally – and further tweaks to the pattern to avoid the last URL match ending with `</pre>`:

```
/(?:auto">)?(.+)(?=(?:\n|<\/pre>))/m
```

You can also check out a [second Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nP0qF6/2) of this twist or try it out in PHP:

```
$re = "/(?:auto\">)?(.+)(?=(?:\\n|<\\/pre>))/m"; 
$str = "auto\">http://url-one.com\nhttp://url-two.com\nhttp://url-three.com\nhttp://url-four.com\nhttp://url-five.com</pre>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches); // NOTE: preg_match_all to match globally
                                                        ^^^^
```

## Which Approach to Choose

The choice between simply adding the `s` modifier or tweaking the pattern, adding the `m` modifier, and matching globally mostly comes down to whether you want a single match with all the URLs (separated by newlines) *or* many matches, each with one of the URLs.

The latter yields the matches below...

```
MATCH 1
1.  [6-24]   `http://url-one.com`
MATCH 2
1.  [25-43]  `http://url-two.com`
MATCH 3
1.  [44-64]  `http://url-three.com`
MATCH 4
1.  [65-84]  `http://url-four.com`
MATCH 5
1.  [85-104] `http://url-five.com`
```

...versus the single match that the original pattern and the `s` modifier yield:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [6-104] `http://url-one.com
             http://url-two.com
             http://url-three.com
             http://url-four.com
             http://url-five.com`
```

Comment: Hey, When i run this regex on the website it puts literally everything in the array, Not just the part between auto and pre. See here: https://regex101.com/r/nP0qF6/3

Comment: @Exoon: In that sea of surrounding characters, narrow down what URL characters to match a bit – e.g. `(?:auto">)?(https?:\/\/[^ \n]+)(?=(?:\n|<\/pre>))`, which you can try in another [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nP0qF6/5).

Comment: @Exoon: Also observe that the original pattern with the `s` modifier (`/auto">(.*?)<\/pre>/s`), followed by `explode("\n", $matches[1])` should give you what you want too.  TMTOWTDI.

Comment: that's almost perfect however it's also grabbing URLs that arn't inside the auto"> </pre> tags. Anyway to fix this ? It got some of these URLs and let others? https://regex101.com/r/nP0qF6/6

Comment: @Exoon: The original pattern with the `s` modifier handles the input in your last Regex101 demo well. See my [Regex101 fork](https://regex101.com/r/gL4aJ7/1). As I indicated above, just follow the `preg_match` call with `explode("\n", $matches[1])` in that case, and it sounds like you should then be set. There is no sense continuing to push down the `preg_match_all` path if it is proving needlessly complicated; I just wanted to show that it could work beyond what you described in your question; but with broader inputs, the `preg_match` approach seems to be the better one to pursue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What happerns if there is two sets of URLs within two different auto"> here </pre> tags though? Any way around that? https://regex101.com/r/gL4aJ7/2